# Best way to do non-flickering, segmented graphics updates in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, graphics

I thought I could just throw this out there and just ask: I have seen Delphi controls that are flawless in terms of graphical effects. Meaning: no flickering, sectioned updates (only redraw the section of a control that is marked as dirty) and smooth scrolling.

I have coded a lot of graphical controls over the years, so I know about double buffering, dibs, bitblts and all the "common" stuff (I always use dibs to draw everything if possible, but there is an overhead). Also know about InvalidateRect and checking TCanvas.ClipRect for the actual rect that needs to be updated. Despite all these typical solutions, I find it very difficult to create the same quality components as say - Developer Express or Razed Components. If the graphics is smooth you can bet the scrollbars (native) flicker, and if the scrollbars and frame is smooth you can swear the background flickers during scrolling.

Is there a standard setup of code to handle this? A sort of best practises that ensures smooth redraws of the entire control -- including the non-client area of a control?

For instance, here is a "bare bone" control which take height for segmented updates (only redraw what is needed). If you create it on a form, try moving a window over it, and watch it replace the parts with colors (see paint method).

Does anyone have a similar base class that can handle non client area redraws without flickering?

```
type

TMyControl = Class(TCustomControl)
private
  (* TWinControl: Erase background prior to client-area paint *)
  procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWmEraseBkgnd);message WM_ERASEBKGND;
Protected
  (* TCustomControl: Overrides client-area paint mechanism *)
  Procedure Paint;Override;

  (* TWinControl: Adjust Win32 parameters for CreateWindow *)
  procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);override;
public
  Constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent);override;
End;


{ TMyControl }

Constructor TMyControl.Create(AOwner:TComponent);
Begin
  inherited Create(Aowner);
  ControlStyle:=ControlStyle - [csOpaque];
end;

procedure TMyControl.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);

  (* When a window has this style set, any areas that its
     child windows occupy are excluded from the update region. *)
  params.ExStyle:=params.ExStyle + WS_CLIPCHILDREN;

  (* Exclude VREDRAW & HREDRAW *)
  with Params.WindowClass do
  Begin
    (* When a window class has either of these two styles set,
       the window contents will be completely redrawn every time it is
       resized either vertically or horizontally (or both) *)
    style:=style - CS_VREDRAW;
    style:=style - CS_HREDRAW;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyControl.Paint;

  (* Inline proc: check if a rectangle is "empty" *)
  function isEmptyRect(const aRect:TRect):Boolean;
  Begin
    result:=(arect.Right=aRect.Left) and (aRect.Bottom=aRect.Top);
  end;

  (* Inline proc: Compare two rectangles *)
  function isSameRect(const aFirstRect:TRect;const aSecondRect:TRect):Boolean;
  Begin
    result:=sysutils.CompareMem(@aFirstRect,@aSecondRect,SizeOf(TRect))
  end;

  (* Inline proc: This fills the background completely *)
  Procedure FullRepaint;
  var
    mRect:TRect;
  Begin
    mRect:=getClientRect;
    AdjustClientRect(mRect);
    Canvas.Brush.Color:=clWhite;
    Canvas.Brush.Style:=bsSolid;
    Canvas.FillRect(mRect);
  end;

begin
  (* A full redraw is only issed if:
      1. the cliprect is empty
      2. the cliprect = clientrect *)
  if isEmptyRect(Canvas.ClipRect)
  or isSameRect(Canvas.ClipRect,Clientrect) then
  FullRepaint else
  Begin
    (* Randomize a color *)
    Randomize;
    Canvas.Brush.Color:=RGB(random(255),random(255),random(255));

    (* fill "dirty rectangle" *)
    Canvas.Brush.Style:=bsSolid;
    Canvas.FillRect(canvas.ClipRect);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyControl.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWmEraseBkgnd);
begin
  message.Result:=-1;
end;
```

**Updated**

I just wanted to add that what did the trick was a combination of:

1. ExcludeClipRect() when drawing the non-clientarea, so you dont overlap with the graphics in the clientarea
2. Catching the WMNCCalcSize message rather than just using the bordersize for measurements. I also had to take height for the edge sizes:

   ```
   XEdge := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);
   YEdge := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYEDGE);
   ```
3. Calling RedrawWindow() with the following flags whenever you have scrollbars that have moved or a resize:

   ```
   mRect:=ClientRect;
   mFlags:=rdw_Invalidate
     or RDW_NOERASE
     or RDW_FRAME
     or RDW_INTERNALPAINT
     or RDW_NOCHILDREN;
   RedrawWindow(windowhandle,@mRect,0,mFlags);
   ```
4. When updating the background during the Paint() method, avoid drawing over possible child objects, like this (see the RDW_NOCHILDREN mentioned above):

   ```
   for x := 1 to ControlCount do
   begin
     mCtrl:=Controls[x-1];
     if mCtrl.Visible then
     Begin
       mRect:=mCtrl.BoundsRect;
       ExcludeClipRect(Canvas.Handle,
       mRect.Left,mRect.Top,
       mRect.Right,mRect.Bottom);
     end;
   end;
   ```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: I have also written a lot of visual controls. In many cases where the visual effects are limited, it works perfectly with clever usage of clip rects, as in my [breadcrumb bar control](http://specials.rejbrand.se/dev/controls/breadcrumb/readme.html). In some other cases, however, where visual feedback and animations are important, I rely on double-buffering, and that has always worked flawlessy for me. You might want to respond manually to the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message, and you might even want to handle the double-buffering manually, by drawing to a `TBitmap` and then `BitBlt` when it suits you.

Comment: There is no 'magic' forumla that works in every scenario, however, so I doubt there will be many useful answers to this question.

Comment: Try http://privat.rejbrand.se/asbutton.exe for a proof that very simply GDI and double-buffering can produce very nice results.

Comment: Well, I already use a backbuffer (double buffering). If I do a full bitblt, then naturally i disable WM_ERASEBKGND (no point clearing an area i will cover with a blit) -- but is there a way to force scrollbars and NCA to be drawn at the same time as the rest?

Comment: isn't double buffering pointless with vista composited rendering?

Comment: I have no idea. But I do notice that say, Developer Express works very fast under both XP and Win7. I have pretty fast code for the DIB stuff, no problems there, it's only a problem when I have a "real" child control involved together with real scrollbars. I tried overriding TScrollBox, just to check, but it produces the same side effects. So I have to conclude that it's something I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Ok.. let's take a practical example: When i get a scroll message, i update the scrollbar positions, and then call -->  RedrawWindow(WindowHandle, @R, 0, rdw_Invalidate or rdw_Frame); to force the window frame and NCA to update. This was taken from a Microsoft C++ "tip" so I presume it's correct. But since it flickers I am open that I could be off the map here ..

Comment: @Jon: You are deriving your controls from `TCustomControl`, I suppose?

Comment: Primarily yes. I have experimented with TWinControl, but yes, most are TCustomControl.

Comment: @David Heffernan: i used to think that too (because i'm sure i read it). But it wasn't the case in practice. A simple thought experiment i went though proves it: 1) fill a window all white - the window should appear all white on screen 2) sometime later fill a windows with all red - the window should appear all red on screen. It doesn't matter how far apart you do those two `FillRect` operations, both should immediately be reflected on screen (i.e. flicker)

Comment: i wanted to mention that you shouldn't be doing *double buffering*/*blits* if the user is running in a remote desktop (i.e. terminal session, remote session) because that ***really*** slows down the drawing. You *want* to draw raw operations on the screen; sending GDI drawing commands is *much* faster than sending a bitmap across broadband. And if you *really* care about you're users, you'll also disable background images, gradients and animations.

Comment: I think you mean "Raize" Components, not "Razed".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> For instance, here is a "bare bone" control which take height for segmented updates (only redraw what is needed). If you create it on a form, try moving a window over it, and watch it replace the parts with colors (see paint method).
>
> Does anyone have a similar base class that can handle non client area redraws without flickering?

Well, your TMyControl does not have a non client area (yet). So I added `BorderWidth := 10;` and now it has. ;)

In general, the non client area's of default Windows windows are automatically painted without flickering, including scrollbars, titles, etc... (at least, I have not witnessed otherwise).

If you want to paint your own border, you have to handle WM_NCPAINT. See this code:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Classes, Controls, Messages, Windows, SysUtils, Graphics;

type
  TMyControl = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint); message WM_NCPAINT;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent);override;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyControl }

constructor TMyControl.Create(AOwner:TComponent);
Begin
  Randomize;
  inherited Create(Aowner);
  ControlStyle:=ControlStyle - [csOpaque];
  BorderWidth := 10;
  Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akBottom, akRight];
end;

procedure TMyControl.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_CLIPCHILDREN;
  with Params.WindowClass do
    style := style and not (CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW);
end;

procedure TMyControl.Paint;
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color := RGB(Random(255), Random(255), Random(255));
  Canvas.FillRect(Canvas.ClipRect);
end;

procedure TMyControl.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

procedure TMyControl.WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint);
var
  DC: HDC;
  R: TRect;
begin
  Message.Result := 0;
  if BorderWidth > 0 then
  begin
    DC := GetWindowDC(Handle);
    try
      R := ClientRect;
      OffsetRect(R, BorderWidth, BorderWidth);
      ExcludeClipRect(DC, R.Left, R.Top, R.Right, R.Bottom);
      SetRect(R, 0, 0, Width, Height);
      Brush.Color := clYellow;
      FillRect(DC, R, Brush.Handle);
    finally
      ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

A few remarks:

- Override CreateParams instead of declaring it virtual. Mind the compiler warning (though I think/hope this is a little mistake).
- You don't have to check for `isEmptyRect` nor `isSameRect`. If `ClipRect` is empty, then there is nothing to draw. This is also the reason why never to call Paint directly, but always through Invalidate or equivalent.
- AdjustClientRect is not needed. It is called internally when needed for its purpose.

And as a bonus, this is exactly how I draw a chessbord component:

```
type
  TCustomChessBoard = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FBorder: TChessBoardBorder;
    FOrientation: TBoardOrientation;
    FSquareSize: TSquareSize;
    procedure BorderChanged;
    procedure RepaintBorder;
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint); message WM_NCPAINT;
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    function GetClientRect: TRect; override;
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure Resize; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    procedure Repaint; override;
  end;

const
  ColCount = 8;
  RowCount = ColCount;

procedure TCustomChessBoard.BorderChanged;
begin
  RepaintBorder;
end;

constructor TCustomChessBoard.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := [csOpaque];
end;

procedure TCustomChessBoard.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  with Params.WindowClass do
    style := style and not (CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW);
end;

function TCustomChessBoard.GetClientRect: TRect;
begin
  Result := Rect(0, 0, FSquareSize * ColCount, FSquareSize * RowCount);
end;

procedure TCustomChessBoard.Paint;

  procedure DrawSquare(Col, Row: Integer);
  var
    R: TRect;
  begin
    R := Bounds(Col * FSquareSize, Row * FSquareSize, FSquareSize, FSquareSize);
    Canvas.Brush.Color := Random(clWhite);
    Canvas.FillRect(R);
  end;

var
  iCol: Integer;
  iRow: Integer;
begin
  with Canvas.ClipRect do
    for iCol := (Left div FSquareSize) to (Right div FSquareSize) do
      for iRow := (Top div FSquareSize) to (Bottom div FSquareSize) do
        DrawSquare(iCol, iRow);
end;

procedure TCustomChessBoard.Repaint;
begin
  inherited Repaint;
  RepaintBorder;
end;

procedure TCustomChessBoard.RepaintBorder;
begin
  if Visible and HandleAllocated then
    Perform(WM_NCPAINT, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TCustomChessBoard.Resize;
begin
  Repaint;
  inherited Resize;
end;

procedure TCustomChessBoard.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

procedure TCustomChessBoard.WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint);
var
  DC: HDC;
  R: TRect;
  R2: TRect;
  SaveFont: HFONT;

  procedure DoCoords(ShiftX, ShiftY: Integer; Alpha, Backwards: Boolean);
  const
    Format = DT_CENTER or DT_NOCLIP or DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER;
    CoordChars: array[Boolean, Boolean] of Char = (('1', '8'), ('A', 'H'));
  var
    i: Integer;
    C: Char;
  begin
    C := CoordChars[Alpha, Backwards];
    for i := 0 to ColCount - 1 do
    begin
      DrawText(DC, PChar(String(C)), 1, R, Format);
      DrawText(DC, PChar(String(C)), 1, R2, Format);
      if Backwards then
        Dec(C)
      else
        Inc(C);
      OffsetRect(R, ShiftX, ShiftY);
      OffsetRect(R2, ShiftX, ShiftY);
    end;
  end;

  procedure DoBackground(Thickness: Integer; AColor: TColor;
    DoPicture: Boolean);
  begin
    ExcludeClipRect(DC, R.Left, R.Top, R.Right, R.Bottom);
    InflateRect(R, Thickness, Thickness);
    if DoPicture then
      with FBorder.Picture.Bitmap do
        BitBlt(DC, R.Left, R.Top, R.Right - R.Left, R.Bottom - R.Top,
          Canvas.Handle, R.Left, R.Top, SRCCOPY)
    else
    begin
      Brush.Color := AColor;
      FillRect(DC, R, Brush.Handle);
    end;
  end;

begin
  Message.Result := 0;
  if BorderWidth > 0 then
    with FBorder do
    begin
      DC := GetWindowDC(Handle);
      try
        { BackGround }
        R := Rect(0, 0, Self.Width, Height);
        InflateRect(R, -Width, -Width);
        DoBackground(InnerWidth, InnerColor, False);
        DoBackground(MiddleWidth, MiddleColor, True);
        DoBackground(OuterWidth, OuterColor, False);
        { Coords }
        if CanShowCoords then
        begin
          ExtSelectClipRgn(DC, 0, RGN_COPY);
          SetBkMode(DC, TRANSPARENT);
          SetTextColor(DC, ColorToRGB(Font.Color));
          SaveFont := SelectObject(DC, Font.Handle);
          try
            { Left and right side }
            R := Bounds(OuterWidth, Width, MiddleWidth, FSquareSize);
            R2 := Bounds(Self.Width - OuterWidth - MiddleWidth, Width,
              MiddleWidth, FSquareSize);
            DoCoords(0, FSquareSize, FOrientation in [boRotate090, boRotate270],
              FOrientation in [boNormal, boRotate090]);
            { Top and bottom side }
            R := Bounds(Width, OuterWidth, FSquareSize, MiddleWidth);
            R2 := Bounds(Width, Height - OuterWidth - MiddleWidth, FSquareSize,
              MiddleWidth);
            DoCoords(FSquareSize, 0,  FOrientation in [boNormal, boRotate180],
              FOrientation in [boRotate090, boRotate180]);
          finally
            SelectObject(DC, SaveFont);
          end;
        end;
      finally
        ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
      end;
    end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Nice example! Yes i had a couple of typos. I could not post the entire source, so i ended up writing a bare-bones just to illustrate how a beginning could be. I use AdjustClientRect quite a lot in my controls, especially in composite layouts. I think the line i was looking for was "Perform(WM_NCPAINT, 0, 0);", will check this out later today -- thanks for all the info!

Comment: Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_CLIPCHILDREN;
If I am not mistaken, this line actually enables WS_EX_COMPOSITED.

Answer (score 19):

Double buffering and fancy drawing tactics are only half the story.  The other half, some would argue the more critical half, is to limit how much of your control is invalidated.

In your comments, you mention that you use `RedrawWindow(handle, @R, 0, rdw_Invalidate or rdw_Frame)`.  What are you setting the `R` rectangle to?  If you set it to your client area rect, then you are redrawing the entire client area of your control.  When scrolling, only a small portion of your control needs to be redrawn - the slice at the "trailing edge" of the scroll direction.  Windows will bitblit the rest of the client area screen to screen to move the existing pixels over in the scroll direction.

Also check whether you have set your window flags to require full redraw on scroll.  I don't recall the flag names offhand, but you want them turned off so that scroll actions only invalidate a slice of your client area.  I believe this is the Windows default.

Even with hardware accelerated graphics, less work is faster than more work. Get your invalidate rects down to the absolute minimum and reduce the number of pixels you're pushing across the system bus.

Comment: The redraw window call is a call that forces the Non-client-area (e.g borders) to invalidate. Is there a better call for doing this? Remember that the NCA is outside the clientrect

Comment: And I completely agree with the rest. I have tried to minimize the use of invalidate/invalidaterect.

Comment: Jon: Try using just the rdw_Frame flag. I have a vague recollection (10 years since last GDI work!) that rdw_Invalidate invalidates the client area and rdw_Frame invalidates the NCA.  If you only want the NCA invalidated, then only use rdw_Frame.

Comment: BTW, why are you invalidating the NCA?

Comment: Because instead of having rulers as a part of the canvas, i isolate them in the frame - that way the canvas scaling is not affected

Answer (score 13):

That is quite an open question. Much tips and answers have already been given. I would like to add two:

- Include `csOpaque` in `ControlStyle` if you paint ClientRect fully,
- Exclude `CS_HREDRAW` and `CS_VREDRAW` from `Params.WindowClass.Style` in `CreateParams`.

Since you are especially interested in drawing on `TScrollingWinControl`, I spend the last couple of hours on reducing the code of a planning component of mine, to get only the necessary painting and scrolling code. It is just an example and by no means fully functional or meant as holy, but it might provide some inspiration:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Classes, Controls, Windows, Messages, ComCtrls, Forms, Grids, Math, CommCtrl,
  SysUtils, StdCtrls, Graphics, Contnrs;

type
  TAwPlanGrid = class;

  TContainer = class(TWinControl)
  private
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure PaintWindow(DC: HDC); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TScrollEvent = procedure(Sender: TControlScrollBar) of object;

  TScroller = class(TScrollingWinControl)
  private
    FOnScroll: TScrollEvent;
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    function DoMouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer;
      MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; override;
    procedure DoScroll(AScrollBar: TControlScrollBar);
    property OnScroll: TScrollEvent read FOnScroll write FOnScroll;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TColumn = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure CMControlChange(var Message: TCMControlChange);
      message CM_CONTROLCHANGE;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TTimeLineHeader = class(TCustomHeaderControl)
  protected
    procedure SectionResize(Section: THeaderSection); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TTimeLineGrid = class(TStringGrid)
  private
    FOnRowHeightsChanged: TNotifyEvent;
    FRowHeightsUpdating: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure RowHeightsChanged; override;
    property OnRowHeightsChanged: TNotifyEvent read FOnRowHeightsChanged
      write FOnRowHeightsChanged;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    function CanFocus: Boolean; override;
  end;

  TTimeLine = class(TContainer)
  private
    FHeader: TTimeLineHeader;
  protected
    TimeLineGrid: TTimeLineGrid;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  THighwayHeader = class(TCustomHeaderControl)
  private
    FSectionWidth: Integer;
    procedure SetSectionWidth(Value: Integer);
  protected
    function CreateSection: THeaderSection; override;
    procedure SectionResize(Section: THeaderSection); override;
    property SectionWidth: Integer read FSectionWidth write SetSectionWidth;
  public
    procedure AddSection(const AText: String);
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  THighwayScroller = class(TScroller)
  private
    procedure WMHScroll(var Message: TWMScroll); message WM_HSCROLL;
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
    procedure WMVScroll(var Message: TWMScroll); message WM_VSCROLL;
  protected
    procedure PaintWindow(DC: HDC); override;
    procedure Resize; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  THighwayColumn = class(TColumn)
  end;

  THighwayColumns = class(TObject)
  private
    FHeight: Integer;
    FItems: TList;
    FParent: TWinControl;
    FWidth: Integer;
    function Add: THighwayColumn;
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): THighwayColumn;
    procedure SetHeight(Value: Integer);
    procedure SetWidth(Value: Integer);
  protected
    property Height: Integer read FHeight write SetHeight;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: THighwayColumn read GetItem; default;
    property Parent: TWinControl read FParent write FParent;
    property Width: Integer read FWidth write SetWidth;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  THighway = class(TContainer)
  private
    procedure HeaderSectionResized(HeaderControl: TCustomHeaderControl;
      Section: THeaderSection);
  protected
    Columns: THighwayColumns;
    Header: THighwayHeader;
    Scroller: THighwayScroller;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TParkingHeader = class(TCustomHeaderControl)
  protected
    procedure SectionResize(Section: THeaderSection); override;
    procedure SetParent(AParent: TWinControl); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TParkingScroller = class(TScroller)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TParkingColumn = class(TColumn)
  private
    FItemHeight: Integer;
    procedure SetItemHeight(Value: Integer);
  protected
    function CanAutoSize(var NewWidth, NewHeight: Integer): Boolean; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    property ItemHeight: Integer read FItemHeight write SetItemHeight;
  end;

  TParking = class(TContainer)
  protected
    Column: TParkingColumn;
    Header: TParkingHeader;
    Scroller: TParkingScroller;
    procedure PaintWindow(DC: HDC); override;
    procedure Resize; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TPlanItem = class(TGraphicControl)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TPlanItems = class(TList)
  public
    procedure DayHeightChanged(OldDayHeight, NewDayHeight: Integer);
  end;

  TAwPlanGrid = class(TContainer)
  private
    FDayHeight: Integer;
    FHighway: THighway;
    FParking: TParking;
    FPlanItems: TPlanItems;
    FTimeLine: TTimeLine;
    function GetColWidth: Integer;
    procedure HighwayScrolled(Sender: TControlScrollBar);
    procedure SetColWidth(Value: Integer);
    procedure SetDayHeight(Value: Integer);
    procedure TimeLineRowHeightsChanged(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure MouseWheelHandler(var Message: TMessage); override;
    procedure Test;
    property ColWidth: Integer read GetColWidth;
    property DayHeight: Integer read FDayHeight;
  end;

function GradientFill(DC: HDC; Vertex: PTriVertex; NumVertex: ULONG;
  Mesh: Pointer; NumMesh, Mode: ULONG): BOOL; stdcall; overload;
  external msimg32 name 'GradientFill';

implementation

function Round2(Value, Rounder: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if Rounder = 0 then Result := Value
  else Result := (Value div Rounder) * Rounder;
end;

// Layout:
//
// - PlanGrid
//   - TimeLine         - Highway            - Parking
//     - TimeLineHeader   - HighwayHeader      - ParkingHeader
//     - TimeLineGrid     - HighwayScroller    - ParkingScroller
//                          - HighwayColumns     - ParkingColumn
//                            - PlanItems          - PlanItems

const
  DaysPerWeek = 5;
  MaxParkingWidth = 300;
  MinColWidth = 50;
  MinDayHeight = 40;
  MinParkingWidth = 60;
  DefTimeLineWidth = 85;
  DividerColor = $0099A8AC;
  DefColWidth = 100;
  DefDayHeight = 48;
  DefWeekCount = 20;

{ TContainer }

constructor TContainer.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := [csOpaque];
end;

procedure TContainer.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  with Params.WindowClass do
    Style := Style and not (CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW);
end;

procedure TContainer.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
begin
  { Eat inherited }
end;

procedure TContainer.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

{ TScroller }

constructor TScroller.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := [csOpaque];
  HorzScrollBar.Tracking := True;
  VertScrollBar.Tracking := True;
end;

procedure TScroller.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  with Params.WindowClass do
    Style := Style and not (CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW);
end;

function TScroller.DoMouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer;
  MousePos: TPoint): Boolean;
var
  Delta: Integer;
begin
  with VertScrollBar do
  begin
    Delta := Increment;
    if WheelDelta > 0 then
      Delta := -Delta;
    if ssCtrl in Shift then
      Delta := DaysPerWeek * Delta;
    Position := Min(Round2(Range - ClientHeight, Increment), Position + Delta);
  end;
  DoScroll(VertScrollBar);
  Result := True;
end;

procedure TScroller.DoScroll(AScrollBar: TControlScrollBar);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnScroll) then
    FOnScroll(AScrollBar);
end;

procedure TScroller.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

{ TColumn }

procedure TColumn.CMControlChange(var Message: TCMControlChange);
begin
  inherited;
  if Message.Inserting then
    Message.Control.Width := Width;
end;

constructor TColumn.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := [csOpaque];
end;

procedure TColumn.Paint;
type
  PTriVertex = ^TTriVertex;
  TTriVertex = packed record
    X: DWORD;
    Y: DWORD;
    Red: WORD;
    Green: WORD;
    Blue: WORD;
    Alpha: WORD;
  end;
var
  Vertex: array[0..1] of TTriVertex;
  GRect: TGradientRect;
begin
  Vertex[0].X := 0;
  Vertex[0].Y := Canvas.ClipRect.Top;
  Vertex[0].Red := $DD00;
  Vertex[0].Green := $DD00;
  Vertex[0].Blue := $DD00;
  Vertex[0].Alpha := 0;
  Vertex[1].X := Width;
  Vertex[1].Y := Canvas.ClipRect.Bottom;
  Vertex[1].Red := $FF00;
  Vertex[1].Green := $FF00;
  Vertex[1].Blue := $FF00;
  Vertex[1].Alpha := 0;
  GRect.UpperLeft := 0;
  GRect.LowerRight := 1;
  GradientFill(Canvas.Handle, @Vertex, 2, @GRect, 1, GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_H);
end;

procedure TColumn.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

{ TTimeLineHeader }

constructor TTimeLineHeader.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := [csOpaque];
  DoubleBuffered := True;
  Sections.Add;
  Sections[0].MinWidth := 40;
  Sections[0].Width := DefTimeLineWidth;
  Sections[0].MaxWidth := DefTimeLineWidth;
  Sections[0].Text := '2011';
end;

procedure TTimeLineHeader.SectionResize(Section: THeaderSection);
begin
  if HasParent then
    Parent.Width := Section.Width;
  inherited SectionResize(Section);
end;

{ TTimeLineGrid }

function TTimeLineGrid.CanFocus: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
end;

constructor TTimeLineGrid.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Align := alCustom;
  Anchors := [akTop, akRight, akBottom];
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
  ColCount := 2;
  ColWidths[0] := 85;
  ControlStyle := [csOpaque];
  FixedCols := 1;
  FixedRows := 0;
  GridLineWidth := 0;
  Options := [goFixedHorzLine, goRowSizing];
  ScrollBars := ssNone;
  TabStop := False;
  Cells[0, 4] := 'Drag day height';
end;

procedure TTimeLineGrid.Paint;
begin
  inherited Paint;
  with Canvas do
    if ClipRect.Right >= Width - 1 then
    begin
      Pen.Color := DividerColor;
      MoveTo(Width - 1, ClipRect.Top);
      LineTo(Width - 1, ClipRect.Bottom);
    end;
end;

procedure TTimeLineGrid.RowHeightsChanged;
begin
  inherited RowHeightsChanged;
  if Assigned(FOnRowHeightsChanged) and (not FRowHeightsUpdating) then
    try
      FRowHeightsUpdating := True;
      FOnRowHeightsChanged(Self);
    finally
      FRowHeightsUpdating := False;
    end;
end;

{ TTimeLine }

constructor TTimeLine.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Align := alLeft;
  Width := DefTimeLineWidth;
  Height := 100;
  FHeader := TTimeLineHeader.Create(Self);
  FHeader.Parent := Self;
  TimeLineGrid := TTimeLineGrid.Create(Self);
  TimeLineGrid.RowCount := DefWeekCount * DaysPerWeek;
  TimeLineGrid.SetBounds(0, FHeader.Height, Width, Height - FHeader.Height);
  TimeLineGrid.Parent := Self;
end;

{ THighwayHeader }

procedure THighwayHeader.AddSection(const AText: String);
begin
  with THeaderSection(Sections.Add) do
    Text := AText;
end;

constructor THighwayHeader.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Align := alCustom;
  Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight];
  ControlStyle := [csOpaque];
  DoubleBuffered := True;
  FullDrag := False;
end;

function THighwayHeader.CreateSection: THeaderSection;
begin
  Result := THeaderSection.Create(Sections);
  Result.MinWidth := MinColWidth;
  Result.Width := FSectionWidth;
end;

procedure THighwayHeader.SectionResize(Section: THeaderSection);
begin
  SectionWidth := Section.Width;
  inherited SectionResize(Section);
end;

procedure THighwayHeader.SetSectionWidth(Value: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if FSectionWidth <> Value then
  begin
    FSectionWidth := Value;
    for i := 0 to Sections.Count - 1 do
      Sections[i].Width := FSectionWidth;
  end;
end;

{ THighwayScroller }

constructor THighwayScroller.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Align := alCustom;
  Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom];
  ControlStyle := [csOpaque];
end;

procedure THighwayScroller.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
begin
  if ControlCount > 0 then
    ExcludeClipRect(DC, 0, 0, ControlCount * Controls[0].Width,
      Controls[0].Height);
  FillRect(DC, ClientRect, Brush.Handle);
end;

procedure THighwayScroller.Resize;
begin
  with VertScrollBar do
    Position := Round2(Position, Increment);
  DoScroll(HorzScrollBar);
  DoScroll(VertScrollBar);
  inherited Resize;
end;

procedure THighwayScroller.WMHScroll(var Message: TWMScroll);
begin
  inherited;
  DoScroll(HorzScrollBar);
end;

procedure THighwayScroller.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  ControlState := ControlState + [csCustomPaint];
  inherited;
  ControlState := ControlState - [csCustomPaint];
end;

procedure THighwayScroller.WMVScroll(var Message: TWMScroll);
var
  NewPos: Integer;
begin
  NewPos := Round2(Message.Pos, VertScrollBar.Increment);
  Message.Pos := NewPos;
  inherited;
  with VertScrollBar do
    if Position <> NewPos then
      Position := Round2(Position, Increment);
  DoScroll(VertScrollBar);
end;

{ THighwayColumns }

function THighwayColumns.Add: THighwayColumn;
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Result := THighwayColumn.Create(nil);
  Index := FItems.Add(Result);
  Result.SetBounds(Index * FWidth, 0, FWidth, FHeight);
  Result.Parent := FParent;
end;

constructor THighwayColumns.Create;
begin
  FItems := TObjectList.Create(True);
end;

destructor THighwayColumns.Destroy;
begin
  FItems.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function THighwayColumns.GetItem(Index: Integer): THighwayColumn;
begin
  Result := FItems[Index];
end;

procedure THighwayColumns.SetHeight(Value: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if FHeight <> Value then
  begin
    FHeight := Value;
    for i := 0 to FItems.Count - 1 do
      Items[i].Height := FHeight;
  end;
end;

procedure THighwayColumns.SetWidth(Value: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if FWidth <> Value then
  begin
    FWidth := Max(MinColWidth, Value);
    for i := 0 to FItems.Count - 1 do
      with Items[i] do
        SetBounds(Left + (FWidth - Width) * i, 0, FWidth, FHeight);
  end;
end;

{ THighway }

constructor THighway.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Align := alClient;
  Width := 100;
  Height := 100;
  Header := THighwayHeader.Create(Self);
  Header.SetBounds(0, 0, Width, Header.Height);
  Header.OnSectionResize := HeaderSectionResized;
  Header.Parent := Self;
  Scroller := THighwayScroller.Create(Self);
  Scroller.SetBounds(0, Header.Height, Width, Height - Header.Height);
  Scroller.Parent := Self;
  Columns := THighwayColumns.Create;
  Columns.Parent := Scroller;
end;

destructor THighway.Destroy;
begin
  Columns.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure THighway.HeaderSectionResized(HeaderControl: TCustomHeaderControl;
  Section: THeaderSection);
begin
  Columns.Width := Section.Width;
  Scroller.HorzScrollBar.Increment := Columns.Width;
  Header.Left := -Scroller.HorzScrollBar.Position;
end;

{ TParkingHeader }

const
  BlindWidth = 2000;

constructor TParkingHeader.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Align := alCustom;
  Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight];
  ControlStyle := [csOpaque];
  DoubleBuffered := True;
  Sections.Add;
  Sections[0].Width := BlindWidth;
  Sections.Add;
  Sections[1].AutoSize := True;
  Sections[1].Text := 'Parked';
end;

procedure TParkingHeader.SectionResize(Section: THeaderSection);
begin
  if (Section.Index = 0) and HasParent then
  begin
    Parent.Width := Max(MinParkingWidth,
      Min(Parent.Width - Section.Width + BlindWidth, MaxParkingWidth));
    Section.Width := BlindWidth;
    Sections[1].Width := Parent.Width - 2;
  end;
  inherited SectionResize(Section);
end;

procedure TParkingHeader.SetParent(AParent: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited SetParent(AParent);
  if HasParent then
  begin
    SetBounds(-BlindWidth + 2, 0, BlindWidth + Parent.Width, Height);
    Sections[1].Width := Parent.Width - 2;
  end;
end;

{ TParkingScroller }

constructor TParkingScroller.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Align := alCustom;
  Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom];
  ControlStyle := [csOpaque];
  HorzScrollBar.Visible := False;
  VertScrollBar.Increment := DefDayHeight;
end;

{ TParkingColumn }

function TParkingColumn.CanAutoSize(var NewWidth, NewHeight: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if HasParent then
    NewHeight := Max(Parent.Height, ControlCount * FItemHeight);
  Result := True;
end;

constructor TParkingColumn.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Align := alTop;
  AutoSize := True;
  FItemHeight := DefDayHeight;
end;

procedure TParkingColumn.SetItemHeight(Value: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if FItemHeight <> Value then
  begin
    FItemHeight := Value;
    for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
      Controls[i].Height := FItemHeight;
    TScroller(Parent).VertScrollBar.Increment := FItemHeight;
  end;
end;

{ TParking }

constructor TParking.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Align := alRight;
  Width := 120;
  Height := 100;
  Header := TParkingHeader.Create(Self);
  Header.Parent := Self;
  Scroller := TParkingScroller.Create(Self);
  Scroller.SetBounds(1, Header.Height, Width, Height - Header.Height);
  Scroller.Parent := Self;
  Column := TParkingColumn.Create(Self);
  Column.Parent := Scroller;
end;

procedure TParking.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  Brush.Color := DividerColor;
  SetRect(R, 0, Header.Height, 1, Height);
  FillRect(DC, R, Brush.Handle);
end;

procedure TParking.Resize;
begin
  Column.AdjustSize;
  inherited Resize;
end;

{ TPlanItem }

constructor TPlanItem.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight];
  ControlStyle := [csOpaque];
  Color := Random(clWhite);
end;

procedure TPlanItem.Paint;
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
  Canvas.FillRect(Canvas.ClipRect);
end;

{ TPlanItems }

procedure TPlanItems.DayHeightChanged(OldDayHeight, NewDayHeight: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
    with TPlanItem(Items[i]) do
      if not (Parent is TParkingColumn) then
      begin
        Top := Trunc(Top * (NewDayHeight / OldDayHeight));
        Height := Trunc(Height * (NewDayHeight / OldDayHeight));
      end;
end;

{ TAwPlanGrid }

constructor TAwPlanGrid.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := [csOpaque];
  TabStop := True;
  Width := 400;
  Height := 200;
  FTimeLine := TTimeLine.Create(Self);
  FTimeLine.TimeLineGrid.OnRowHeightsChanged := TimeLineRowHeightsChanged;
  FTimeLine.Parent := Self;
  FParking := TParking.Create(Self);
  FParking.Parent := Self;
  FHighway := THighway.Create(Self);
  FHighway.Scroller.OnScroll := HighwayScrolled;
  FHighway.Parent := Self;
  FPlanItems := TPlanItems.Create;
  SetColWidth(DefColWidth);
  SetDayHeight(DefDayHeight);
  FHighway.Columns.Height := DefWeekCount * DaysPerWeek * FDayHeight;
end;

destructor TAwPlanGrid.Destroy;
begin
  FPlanItems.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TAwPlanGrid.GetColWidth: Integer;
begin
  Result := FHighway.Columns.Width;
end;

procedure TAwPlanGrid.HighwayScrolled(Sender: TControlScrollBar);
begin
  if Sender.Kind = sbVertical then
    FTimeLine.TimeLineGrid.TopRow := Sender.Position div FDayHeight
  else
  begin
    FHighway.Header.Left := -Sender.Position;
    FHighway.Header.Width := FHighway.Width + Sender.Position;
  end;
end;

procedure TAwPlanGrid.MouseWheelHandler(var Message: TMessage);
var
  X: Integer;
begin
  with Message do
  begin
    X := ScreenToClient(SmallPointToPoint(TCMMouseWheel(Message).Pos)).X;
    if X >= FParking.Left then
      Result := FParking.Scroller.Perform(CM_MOUSEWHEEL, WParam, LParam)
    else
      Result := FHighway.Scroller.Perform(CM_MOUSEWHEEL, WParam, LParam);
  end;
  if Message.Result = 0 then
    inherited MouseWheelHandler(Message);
end;

procedure TAwPlanGrid.SetColWidth(Value: Integer);
begin
  if ColWidth <> Value then
  begin
    FHighway.Columns.Width := Value;
    FHighway.Header.SectionWidth := ColWidth;
    FHighway.Scroller.HorzScrollBar.Increment := ColWidth;
  end;
end;

procedure TAwPlanGrid.SetDayHeight(Value: Integer);
var
  OldDayHeight: Integer;
begin
  if FDayHeight <> Value then
  begin
    OldDayHeight := FDayHeight;
    FDayHeight := Max(MinDayHeight, Round2(Value, 4));
    FTimeLine.TimeLineGrid.DefaultRowHeight := FDayHeight;
    FHighway.Columns.Height := DefWeekCount * DaysPerWeek * FDayHeight;
    FHighway.Scroller.VertScrollBar.Increment := FDayHeight;
    FPlanItems.DayHeightChanged(OldDayHeight, FDayHeight);
  end;
end;

procedure TAwPlanGrid.Test;
var
  i: Integer;
  PlanItem: TPlanItem;
begin
  Randomize;
  Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akBottom, akRight];
  for i := 0 to 3 do
    FHighway.Columns.Add;
  FHighway.Header.AddSection('Drag col width');
  FHighway.Header.AddSection('Column 2');
  FHighway.Header.AddSection('Column 3');
  FHighway.Header.AddSection('Column 4');
  for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    PlanItem := TPlanItem.Create(Self);
    PlanItem.Parent := FParking.Column;
    PlanItem.Top := i * DefDayHeight;
    PlanItem.Height := DefDayHeight;
    FPlanItems.Add(PlanItem);
  end;
  for i := 0 to 3 do
  begin
    PlanItem := TPlanItem.Create(Self);
    PlanItem.Parent := FHighway.Columns[i];
    PlanItem.Top := (i + 3) * DefDayHeight;
    PlanItem.Height := DefDayHeight;
    FPlanItems.Add(PlanItem);
  end;
  SetFocus;
end;

procedure TAwPlanGrid.TimeLineRowHeightsChanged(Sender: TObject);
var
  iRow: Integer;
begin
  with FTimeLine.TimeLineGrid do
    for iRow := 0 to RowCount - 1 do
      if RowHeights[iRow] <> DefaultRowHeight then
      begin
        SetDayHeight(RowHeights[iRow]);
        Break;
      end;
end;

end.
```

Testing code:

```
with TAwPlanGrid.Create(Self) do
begin
  SetBounds(10, 100, 600, 400);
  Parent := Self;
  Test;
end;
```

My 2 cts.

Comment: It is very interestig that you mention the flags, I was thinking about those very flags last night -- Thanks to the example code, i'll try it after work!

Answer (score 9):

i have seen the argument, and try to employ it in practice, that you should never draw over the same pixels more than once.

If you're drawing a red square on a white background then you paint everything white *except where the red square will go*, then you "fill in" the red square:

[image]

There's no flicker, and you're doing fewer drawing operations.

That is an extreme example of *only invalidate what you have to*, as [*dthorp* mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363954/best-way-to-do-non-flickering-segmented-graphics-updates-in-delphi/6364835#6364835). If you're scrolling a control, use `ScrollWindow` to have the graphics subsystem move what's already there, and then just *fill in* the missing bit at the bottom.

There are going to be times where you **have** to paint the same pixels multiple times; ClearType text is the best example. ClearType rendering requires access to the pixels underneath - which means you're going to **have** to fill an area with white, then draw your text over it.

But even that can usually be mitigated by measuring the `rects` of the text you're going to render, fill `clWhite` everywhere *else*, then have `DrawText` *fill in* the empty areas - using a white `HBRUSH` background:

[image]

But that trick cannot work when drawing text on a gradient, or arbitrary existing content - so there will be flicker. In that case you have to double buffer in some way. (Although don't double buffer if the user is in a remote session - flickering is better than slow drawing).

---

**Bonus Chatter**: Now that i've explained *why* you shouldn't double buffer content when the user is running though Remote Desktop (i.e. Terminal Services), you now know what this Internet Explorer advanced option means, what it does, and why it is off by default:

[image]

Comment: If you are going to ape Raymond's style (and why not), then you may as well take the opportunity to put a link into his article discussing double buffering and remote desktop which, if memory serves, was part of his paying your taxes series.

Comment: @David Heffernan: You're noticing the *Bonus chatter* wording?

Comment: Yes I am alert to such things.

Comment: @David Heffernan @Ian Boyd,
I noted too... So I am adding the article. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/01/03/508694.aspx