# TScrollBox with customized flat border color and width?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I'm trying to create a TScrollBox with flat border instead of the ugly "Ctl3D" one.

Here is what I have tried, yet the border is not visible:

```
type
  TScrollBox = class(Forms.TScrollBox)
  private
    procedure WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint); message WM_NCPAINT;
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

...

constructor TScrollBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
  BorderWidth := 1; // This will handle the client area
end;

procedure TScrollBox.WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint);
var
  DC: HDC;
  R: TRect;
  FrameBrush: HBRUSH;
begin
  inherited;
  DC := GetWindowDC(Handle);
  GetWindowRect(Handle, R);
  // InflateRect(R, -1, -1);
  FrameBrush := CreateSolidBrush(ColorToRGB(clRed)); // clRed is here for testing
  FrameRect(DC, R, FrameBrush);
  DeleteObject(FrameBrush);
  ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
end;
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

I would like to customize the border color & width so I **can't** use `BevelKind = bkFlat`, plus `bkFlat` "breaks" with RTL BidiMode and looks really bad.

Comment: I actually like the classic Windows 3D style. Reminds me of simpler days.

Comment: I think you have to mimic `TWinControl.WMNCPaint`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, you have to draw the border in a `WM_NCPAINT` message handler. The device context you obtain with `GetWindowDC` is relative to the control, while the rectangle you obtain with `GetWindowRect` is relative to the screen.

The correct rectangle is gotten e.g. by `SetRect(R, 0, 0, Width, Height);`

Subsequently, set `BorderWidth` as your wish and `ClientRect` should follow accordingly. If not, then compensate by overriding `GetClientRect`. Here are a [few examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6374461/757830).

Call the inherited chain of message handlers before your own code, so the scroll bars (when needed) will be drawn correctly. All in all, it should look like:

```
type
  TScrollBox = class(Forms.TScrollBox)
  private
    procedure WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint); message WM_NCPAINT;
  protected
    procedure Resize; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

...    

constructor TScrollBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  BorderWidth := 1;
end;

procedure TScrollBox.Resize;
begin
  Perform(WM_NCPAINT, 0, 0);
  inherited Resize;
end;

procedure TScrollBox.WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint);
var
  DC: HDC;
  B: HBRUSH;
  R: TRect;
begin
  inherited;
  if BorderWidth > 0 then
  begin
    DC := GetWindowDC(Handle);
    B := CreateSolidBrush(ColorToRGB(clRed));
    try
      SetRect(R, 0, 0, Width, Height);
      FrameRect(DC, R, B);
    finally
      DeleteObject(B);
      ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
    end;
  end;
  Message.Result := 0;
end;
```

Comment: +1!!! `MapWindowPoints` form `TWinControl.WMNCPaint` gave me the idea that I use the wrong coordinates. `SetRect(R, 0, 0, Width, Height)` did the trick. p.s: should I `inhrited` first or should I return `Message.Result := 0;` like you did?

Comment: Call the inherited message handers in front, because that's wherein the scroll bars are drawn. Return zero when processed.